# Replace Content of a Div on single page site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been building a site based off a template I found online, a would appreciate any help getting it to function how I want it to. Currently its set up with filters that allow you to sort through multiple thumbnails. However I want the links that currently act as "filters" to instead replace the div where all the thumbnails show up.

I've searched around here looking at jQuery, to replace `div` content, including replacing the contents of the div, and hiding divs and showing them on click. Nothing I seem to do works though.

Ideally, I'd wrap the current `UL` in a `div` named "designprojects" and then when I click a filter that div gets replaced with a new one that has project info in it.

Here is the current HTML and Javascript that the site uses to make the filters function:

```js
filter = function() {
  if ($('#projects').length > 0) {
    var $container = $('#projects');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
      $container.isotope({
        // options
        animationEngine: 'best-available',
        itemSelector: '.item-thumbs',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
      });
    });


    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
      $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

    $optionLinks.click(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      // don't proceed if already selected
      if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        return false;
      }
      var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
      $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $this.addClass('selected');

      // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
      var options = {},
        key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
        value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
      // parse 'false' as false boolean
      value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
      options[key] = value;
      if (key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function') {
        // changes in layout modes need extra logic
        changeLayoutMode($this, options)
      } else {
        // otherwise, apply new options
        $container.isotope(options);
      }

      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Portfolio Projects -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3">
    <!-- Filter -->
    <nav id="options" class="work-nav">
      <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
        <li class="type-work">Projects</li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".StarbucksCSR">Starbucks CSR Project</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Filter -->

  </div>

  <div class="span9">
    <div class="row">
      <section id="projects">
        <ul class="thumbs">
          <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
          <li class="item-thumbs span3 StarbucksCSR">
            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Project Title" href="_include/img/work/full/url.jpg">
              <span class="overlay-img"></span>
              <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
            </a>
            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/url.jpg" alt="Project info">
          </li>
          <!-- End Item Project -->

        </ul>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Portfolio Projects -->
```

To recap, when I click "All Projects" I want to see thumbnails that I can click and make full screen (current function, also want this to be the default).

When I click a project name, I want the `div` that holds all the thumbnails to be replaced with a paragraph about the project, and additonal thumbnails that can be clicked to extend to full screen.

My current progress can be seen at [www.codyshipman.com](http://www.codyshipman.com)

Answer (score 1):

Look in the jQuery's `.html()` function. If you want to replace content of a `<div>` element, pass the new content as parameter to the `.html(newContentAsString)` function, for that `<div>` element. Look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for more info.